# xml centered textview to much to left

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I try to create somekind of stroke on top of my screen which displays 4 things. An backbutton on the left, the level name in the center and scoreInfoOne and scoreInfoTwo on the right, but below each other. I use following code, but the strange thing is that the level name doesn't appear to be centered, the longer the value of scoreInfoTwo is, the more the level name is on the left. Any ideas?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#25ab89"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivBackButton"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvScoreBoard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="level"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="2dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvScoreInfoOne"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="0/30"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvScoreInfoTwo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="score:"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12dp" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child views must set the layout_width to zero:

```
android:layout_width="0px"
```

So your layout would then look like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="#25ab89"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivBackButton"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvScoreBoard"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="level"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingRight="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvScoreInfoOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="0/30"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvScoreInfoTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="score:"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="12dp" >
        </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you very much, this does the trick! Can you explain me what went wrong then? I used wrap content, it shouldn't take in more place than the weight I gave it, isn't it?

Comment: `wrap_content` will ignore the weight values. You should always use `0px` (or any other measurement - `dip`, `dp`, etc) in the direction of the layout. So for a weighted, horizontal layout you set width to 0, and for a vertically oriented layout, you would set `layout_height` to zero.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you cannot use `android:layout_gravity="anything"` in a `LinearLayout`. For `LinearLayout`s you use the weights to define how much space you want to use. For what you are trying to do, I suggest using a `RelativeLayout` then you can just define where you want your `TextView` or other items by using `android:layout_below="@+id/other_textview` and there are lots of `android:layout_[direction]` to choose from, and you can use `layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` with these.

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="#25ab89">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivBackButton"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvScoreBoard"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_below="@id/ivBackButton"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="level"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvScoreInfoOne"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvScoreBoard"
                    android:alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="0/30"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvScoreInfoTwo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvScoreInfoTwo"
                    android:alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="score:"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt, should work too.. It's less code. First three items are next to each other, so I should use onRightOf I guess.

Comment: I just tried to get a picture of what you were trying to do, then write my code to match. You can definitely change it around quickly by using the `layout_toRightOf=""` etc. very easily.